# `let...else` statements are unstable when i need to use pallet-contract

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-contracts-node

i want to add pallet-contract in my project , it show me error when run this command : `cargo check`
**Error :**

```
     error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:190:4
      |
  190 |             let Ok(end) = args.end.base10_parse::<u32>() else { return invalid_param(args.end.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:189:4
      |
  189 |             let Ok(start) = args.start.base10_parse::<u32>() else { return invalid_param(args.start.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:188:4
      |
  188 |             let Ok(args) = syn::parse::<RangeArgs>(args) else { return invalid_param(typ.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:186:4
      |
  186 |             let Some(segment) = tpath.path.segments.last() else { return invalid_param(typ.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:185:4
      |
  185 |             let Type::Path(tpath) = typ else { return invalid_param(typ.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:178:4
      |
  178 |             let Some(name_char) = name.chars().next() else { return invalid_param_name() };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:164:4
      |
  164 |             let Pat::Ident(ident) = &*arg.pat else { return invalid_param(arg.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:163:4
      |
  163 |             let FnArg::Typed(arg) = arg else { return invalid_param(arg.span()) };
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:215:6
      |
  215 | /                     let Some(origin) = expr_call.args.first().cloned() else {
  216 | |                         return Some(Err(Error::new(expr_call.span(), "Single-item extrinsic calls must specify their origin as th...
  217 | |                     };
      | |______________________^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:293:3
      |
  293 |         let Item::Fn(func) = stmt else { return None };
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:681:6
      |
  681 |                     let Some(segment) = expr_path.path.segments.last() else { return call_err(); };
      |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
     --> /home/kianoush/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/52d72b3/frame/support/procedural/src/benchmark.rs:687:6
      |
  687 |                     let Ok(_) = syn::parse::<Token![_]>(tokens.to_token_stream().into()) else { return call_err(); };
      |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |
      = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
      = help: add `#![feature(let_else)]` to the crate attributes to enable

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
  error: could not compile `frame-support-procedural` due to 12 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

i did these steps :

[Repository](https://github.com/dortajkianoush/substrate_dex)

**Step One : Add Depency Pallets**

```
    pallet-contracts = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
pallet-contracts-primitives = { version = "7.0.0", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git",  " branch" = "polkadot-v0.9.35" }
```

**Step Two : Add Pallets Config**

```
    parameter_types! {
    pub TombstoneDeposit: Balance = deposit(
        1,
        <pallet_contracts::Pallet<Runtime>>::contract_info_size()
    );
    pub DepositPerContract: Balance = TombstoneDeposit::get();
    pub const DepositPerStorageByte: Balance = deposit(0, 1);
    pub const DepositPerStorageItem: Balance = deposit(1, 0);
    pub RentFraction: Perbill = Perbill::from_rational(1u32, 30 * DAYS);
    pub const SurchargeReward: Balance = 150 * MILLICENTS;
    pub const SignedClaimHandicap: u32 = 2;
    pub const MaxValueSize: u32 = 16 * 1024;
    // The lazy deletion runs inside on_initialize.
    pub DeletionWeightLimit: Weight = AVERAGE_ON_INITIALIZE_RATIO *
     BlockWeights::get().max_block;
    // The weight needed for decoding the queue should be less or equal than a fifth
    // of the overall weight dedicated to the lazy deletion.
    pub DeletionQueueDepth: u32 = ((DeletionWeightLimit::get() / (
        <Runtime as pallet_contracts::Config>::WeightInfo::on_initialize_per_queue_item(1) -
        <Runtime as pallet_contracts::Config>::WeightInfo::on_initialize_per_queue_item(0)
     )) / 5) as u32;

    pub Schedule: pallet_contracts::Schedule<Runtime> = Default::default();
}

impl pallet_contracts::Config for Runtime {
    type Time = Timestamp;
    type Randomness = RandomnessCollectiveFlip;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type Event = Event;
    type RentPayment = ();
    type SignedClaimHandicap = SignedClaimHandicap;
    type TombstoneDeposit = TombstoneDeposit;
    type DepositPerContract = DepositPerContract;
    type DepositPerStorageByte = DepositPerStorageByte;
    type DepositPerStorageItem = DepositPerStorageItem;
    type RentFraction = RentFraction;
    type SurchargeReward = SurchargeReward;
    type WeightPrice = pallet_transaction_payment::Module<Self>;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_contracts::weights::SubstrateWeight<Self>;
    type ChainExtension = ();
    type DeletionQueueDepth = DeletionQueueDepth;
    type DeletionWeightLimit = DeletionWeightLimit;
    type Call = Call;
    /// The safest default is to allow no calls at all.
    ///
    /// Runtimes should whitelist dispatchables that are allowed to be called from contracts
    /// and make sure they are stable. Dispatchables exposed to contracts are not allowed to
    /// change because that would break already deployed contracts. The `Call` structure itself
    /// is not allowed to change the indices of existing pallets, too.
    type CallFilter = Nothing;
    type Schedule = Schedule;
    type CallStack = [pallet_contracts::Frame<Self>; 31];
}
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `rustc` to at least 1.65. With 1.65 this syntax was stabilized.