# `let...else` statements are unstable

Tags: rust, runtime-upgrade, substrate-parachain-template

trying to update to the latest polkadot-v0.9.37

when i `cargo check` i get:

```
   Checking sc-executor-wasmi v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.37#946507ba)
    Checking sp-io v7.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.37#946507ba)
error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
   --> /Users/ramsey/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/946507b/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:786:4
    |
786 | /             let Ok(public_key) = ed25519_dalek::PublicKey::from_bytes(&pub_key.0) else {
787 | |                 return false
788 | |             };
    | |______________^
    |
    = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information

error[E0658]: `let...else` statements are unstable
   --> /Users/ramsey/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/946507b/primitives/io/src/lib.rs:790:4
    |
790 | /             let Ok(sig) = ed25519_dalek::Signature::from_bytes(&sig.0) else {
791 | |                 return false
792 | |             };
    | |______________^
    |
```

my versions are:

`rustv -V`:
`rustc 1.64.0`

`rustup show`

```
active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.67.0 (fc594f156 2023-01-24)
```

and

`rustup +nightly show`

```
active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.69.0-nightly (75a0be98f 2023-02-05)
```

I notice that rustv -V is still on an old version even if i use `rustup default stable`, on a macos m2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`let...else\` statements are unstable when i need to use pallet-contract](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6946/let-else-statements-are-unstable-when-i-need-to-use-pallet-contract)

Comment: no, but i notice my rustc -V is not changing when i use rustup default stable. Its stuck at 1.64.0

Comment: Any chance you have a rust toolchain file in your repo?

Comment: @Purple_Turtle no, but maybe its the way i installed rustc initially, which i doubt was anything other than via substrate.io docs, so i am confused as to what it could be, i am asking the Rust element channel to find out because theres no simple breadcrumbs when searching

Comment: i had multiple installations on the same machines : )

Answer (score 3):

The answer to why `rustc --version` and `rustup show` versions were different was because I had `rustc` installed in various ways on the same machine.

Run the command `which -a rustc` to find out their locations.

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/rustc
/opt/homebrew/bin/rustc
/Users/ramsey/.cargo/bin/rustc
```

In my situation I have `brew`-installed version(s), which I don't need.

`brew uninstall rust`

and then run `rustc --version` and `rustup show`, and the versions now match.

Now the error `let...else are unstable` has disappeared.

Comment: `which` is standard on MacOS, but `which` and in particular `which -a` is not portable. The proper portable solution is `type`; if you are using Zsh or Windows, try `whence`